# middle screen in cocos2d-2?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Did they changed the positioning method in this cocos2d version 2 ?

i do this :

```
mainBack=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"plus.png"];
            mainBack.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
            NSLog(@"THE PLACE IS IN:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(mainBack.position) );
            [self addChild:mainBack z:0];
```

its not in the middle but next to it. 
it does prints 160, 240.
i am in a retina display when the image is twice bigger .

why is it not in the middle of the screen ?

thanks.

Comment: no problem in your code. it set middle of the screen. 1) check your image.. 2) check winSize size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u r doing this in ur init method of first scene. Try same thing in onEnter method..everything works fine.

```
-(void)onEnter
{
  [super onEnter];

   CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

   mainBack=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"plus.png"];  
   mainBack.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
   mainBack.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
   NSLog(@"THE PLACE IS IN:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(mainBack.position) );
   [self addChild:mainBack z:0];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but whats the different ? i dont think there should be any different from init and onEnter ? and what is the anchor point of 0.5 you have added ?

Comment: btw , it didnt worked , i have tried your solution. still not in the middle

Comment: @user1280535, r u placed plus-hd.png image? what is self ? CCLayer?